# JQuery UI resizable/#constrain-area -> Constrain not smalle than child div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

so far JqueryUI works that I can make my resizable `<div></div>` element not bigger then its parent, like in this example: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#constrain-area

This means I cannot make the blue area bigger than the orange one, because `<div>blue</div>` is the child of `<div>orange</div>`

What I want to do is the opposite: The `<div>orange</div>` should not be allowed to resized smaller then that it still fits it children `<div>blue</div>` and `<div>red</div>`

Here is an example:
[image]

Because we resize from the bottom/right corner the maximum minus resize should be:
[image]

The DOM Tree looks like this:

[image]

My Question is, if it is possible to do such a restraining with JQueryUI and if not does anybody know a solution or another JavaScript Library that supports restraining like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that behavior using JQuery, [here you can find a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/w3no7ee0/)

```
  var minWidth = 0;
  var minHeight = 0;

  $.each( $('#main'), function(i, divs) {
     $('div', divs).each(function() {
        var tmpWidth = $(this).position().left + $(this).width();
            if (tmpWidth > minWidth)
        minWidth = tmpWidth;
      var tmpHeight = $(this).position().top + $(this).height();
            if (tmpHeight > minHeight)
        minHeight = tmpHeight;
     });
  });
  $('.orange').resizable({
            resize : function(event, ui){
            $(this).resizable( "option", "minWidth", minWidth);
            $(this).resizable( "option", "minHeight", minHeight);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Does exactely the job